# How do I add olcAuditLogConfig to openldap on Centos 6

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap, centos6

Regarding to 'man slapo-auditlog' I should just need to add the following.

```
dn: olcOverlay=auditlog,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAuditLogConfig
olcOverlay: auditlog
olcAuditlogFile: /tmp/auditlog.ldif
```

First the "olcOverlay=auditlog" is not installed by default on Centos 6. So i cant add this to anything. If I remove "changetype: add" I will get this error.

```
additional info: objectClass: value #1 invalid per syntax
```

I found out that I could create my own cn=module, and after that olcAuditLogConfig existed, and I could execute the above LDIF. But I still don't get any auditlogs.

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap/
olcModuleLoad: auditlog.la
```

My LDAP-setup can be found here (now slightly modified on my own server)

[How do I configure LDAP on Centos 6 for user authentication in the most secure and correct way?](https://serverfault.com/questions/323497/how-do-i-configure-ldap-on-centos-6-for-user-authentication-in-the-most-secure-a/323569#323569)

Answer (score 2):

I have now got everything to work and I was very close to the solution. It was a permission problem. This is how you add the auditlog to openldap installed on Centos 6.

First enable the module.

```
ldapadd -H ldaps://ldap.example.net -x -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -w secret << EOF
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap/
olcModuleLoad: auditlog.la
EOF
```

Setup a folder where ldap has permission to write.

```
mkdir slapd
chmod 755 /var/log/slapd/
chown ldap:ldap /var/log/slapd/
ls -alvhZ /var/log/slapd/
```

And then configure the olcAuditLogConfig overlay.

```
ldapadd -H ldaps://ldap.example.net -x -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -w secret << EOF
dn: olcOverlay=auditlog,olcDatabase={1}bdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAuditLogConfig
olcOverlay: auditlog
olcAuditlogFile: /var/log/slapd/auditlog.log
EOF
```

Insert something to the database.

```
ldapadd -H ldaps://ldap.example.net -x -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -w secret << EOF
dn: cn=management11191,ou=group,dc=example,dc=net
cn: management11191
objectClass: posixGroup
gidNumber: 2005
memberUid: user1
memberUid: user3
EOF
```

And check the auditlog file, if you see any contents it works.

```
$ cat /var/log/slapd/auditlog.log
...
$ ls -alvhZ  /var/log/slapd/auditlog.log
-rw-r--r--. ldap ldap unconfined_u:object_r:slapd_log_t:s0 /var/log/slapd/auditlog.log
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to install the `openldap-servers-overlays` package:

   ```
   Name       : openldap-servers-overlays
   Arch       : x86_64
   Version    : 2.3.43
   Release    : 12.el5_7.9
   Size       : 358 k
   Repo       : installed
   Summary    : Overlays for OpenLDAP server.
   URL        : http://www.openldap.org/
   License    : OpenLDAP
   Description: OpenLDAP is an open-source suite of LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access
              : Protocol) applications and development tools. LDAP is a set of
              : protocols for accessing directory services (usually phone book style
              : information, but other information is possible) over the Internet,
              : similar to the way DNS (Domain Name System) information is propagated
              : over the Internet.
              : 
              : This package contains overlay modules for OpenLDAP server daemon.
   ```
2. Uncomment the `auditlog` module in `slapd.conf`:

   ```
   modulepath  /usr/lib64/openldap
   moduleload auditlog.la
   ```
3. Specify the `auditlog` file:

   ```
   database    bdb

   overlay     auditlog
   auditlog    /tmp/audit.log

   suffix      "dc=domain,dc=com"
   rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com"
   ```
4. Modify/add some values to the attributes and take a look at the
   above log, you will see something like this:

   ```
   # modify 1319524581 dc=domain,dc=com cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com
   dn: cn=xx,ou=yy,dc=domain,dc=com
   changetype: modify
   replace: initials
   initials: Hai
   initials: Do
   -
   replace: entryCSN
   entryCSN: 20111025063621Z#000000#00#000000
   -
   replace: modifiersName
   modifiersName: cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com
   -
   replace: modifyTimestamp
   modifyTimestamp: 20111025063621Z
   -
   # end replace 1319524581
   ```

Comment: Looks like openldap-servers-overlays are only available in Centos 5. Look here ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/centos/5/updates/x86_64/RPMS/ and ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/centos/6/updates/x86_64/RPMS/... I think I'm close to a solution now, looks like a permission problem on my box.

Comment: Does `/usr/lib64/openldap/auditlog.la` exist?

Comment: Yes it exists. But everything works for me now. After I figured out how to add the modules, it got a permission problem. But no errors in any logs. So I was unsure if the module was added in the correct way or not. See my posted answer to this question to see how I solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Run `yum provides */auditlog.la` to see the `openldap-servers` is already provides `auditlog.la` on CentOS 6.

Comment: Your guess was right, they have moved auditlog.la to openldap-servers. (soon a new LDAP-question)