# How do I get openldap on Centos 6 to write anything to it's log files

Tags: ldap, openldap, centos6

I don't get any information in my log file for openldap on my Centos 6 server. This is how i configured it. SELinux is disabled at the moment.

First created a folder where I'd like to store the log files.

```
mkdir /var/log/slapd
chmod 755 /var/log/slapd/
chown ldap:ldap /var/log/slapd/
```

Then did the configuration.

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -w secret -b cn=config cn=config
dn: cn=config
changetype:modify
replace: olcLogFile
olcLogFile: /var/log/slapd/slapd.log
-
replace: olcLogLevel
olcLogLevel: conns filter config acl stats shell
EOF
```

Just to be safe I restarted the service

```
service openldap restart
```

It does create the file, but don't write anything into the file. Of course I did some searches and updates to the LDAP-server, so it gets connections and stuff to log.

```
$ ls -alh
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x. 2 ldap ldap 4.0K Oct 25 14:27 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4.0K Oct 25 14:10 ..    
-rw-r--r--. 1 ldap ldap    0 Oct 25 14:33 slapd.log
```

My LDAP-setup can be found here (now slightly modified on my own server)

[How do I configure LDAP on Centos 6 for user authentication in the most secure and correct way?](https://serverfault.com/questions/323497/how-do-i-configure-ldap-on-centos-6-for-user-authentication-in-the-most-secure-a/323569#323569)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I haven't tried `olcLogFile` but by default, OpenLDAP log all information to rsyslog's `local4` facility.

Add the following line to `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or /etc/rsyslog.d/ldap.conf:

```
local4.*                        /var/log/ldap.log
```

Restart the `rsyslog` service and check out this log.

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. It was /etc/rsyslog.conf on my box. Same, same but different.

Comment: Depend on which syslog daemon is in use.

Comment: I created a file called `/etc/rsyslog.d/slapd.conf`and put the contents inside this file. I didn't modify `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

Answer (score 6):

`olcLogFile` is only used on Windows because it lacks syslog.

The way to do log on your system is which that @quanta answered.

Comment: "olcLogFile is only used on Windows because it lacks syslog.": This is not true, see `slapd-config(5)` or [my answer](http://serverfault.com/a/801839/269679).

Answer (score 1):

As the reasoning regarding `olcLogFile` given in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/499902/269679) is not true, I have to correct this.

Quoting the relevant part of `slapd-config(5)`:

```
olcLogFile: <filename>
            Specify a file for recording debug log messages. By default
            these messages only go to stderr and are not recorded any‐
            where else. Specifying a logfile copies messages to both
            stderr and the logfile.
```