# Configuring openLDAP in CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap, centos6

I have followed the instructions found in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/323497) until the part that I have to do an ldapadd using "cn=Manager,dc=syco,dc=net" as DN. However, I am getting the error Invalid Credentials (49) whenever I do this. What should I do? Thank you very much.

(Sorry for creating this new question instead of commenting there instead. As you can see, my reputation is yet to allow me to do so.)

Comment: So how did you go about the customisation he mentioned? Namely the passwords ...

Comment: I did not go really execute the whole script in one bash. I executed each line in that link one by one on the command line. So yes, I have modified the passwords according to my preference.

Also, I have tried calling slappasswd to get a new SSHA of the password and replace the existing one. However, it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I was simply careless with adding/editing the olcRootPW field for the slapd.d configuration files. I missed putting the {SSHA} to indicate the encryption method for the RootDN.